# Stochastic Methods for Image Deconvolution Problem

Tags: image-processing, deconvolution, stochastic, inverse-problem

If we convolve an image with a point spread function and from the resulting image to find the input image, can we use any stochastic approaches? I feel like we will not be able to. A single image seems to me a deterministic quantity and I cannot think of any way to approach this deconvolution problem in a stochastic way. However, I am not sure and I want to know if there is a way. Any help is appreciated

Comment: Any approach which takes into account the noise in the image is stochastic.

Comment: I see, thank you so much @Royi !

Comment: Would you accept this as an answer?

Comment: Though I could not figure out how it would work in the real case, yes, I would accept it as an answer. But if you are asking for me to accept your comment as the approved answer,  I would like to say that you have written it as a comment not an answer, hence I am not able to accept it as the answer

Comment: Hi, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Deconvolution method which takes into account the noise in the image is basically a stochastic approach.

Usually, the model for Deconvolution is:

[image]

So having the noise in there makes it a problem with stochastic properties.

**Remark**
If by stochastic you meant sampling from the Posterior Distribution then you may have a look at [Stochastic Image Denoising by Sampling from the Posterior Distribution](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.09552) (Though it is not about Deconvolution but on Denoising).

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation!